# How to know if PC is 'really' idle using python? Windows Idle time has different defination that what I am looking for

Tags: python, windows-7-x64, taskmanager

I want to shut down my PC if there are no applications running i.e. PC is idle. I have written a code to get window's idle time in python. But windows idle time is "Time for which PC has no interaction with user i.e. mouse or keyboard input". This idle time increases even though applications are running.

How to check if there are no applications are running and I can shut down my PC? I have thought of CPU usage in task manager, but I don't think that will help my task.

I use python 2.7 on a Win7 64bit.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Please don't forget to wear a sweater when you go out at night. - @peterh-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @BerryTsakala Sorry for the inconvenience - note, I also did a lot to improve the post.

Comment: i was joking about the other comments